# float to uint16 conversion blowing numbers up in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, casting, type-conversion

My data has daily `indate`s from 1947 to 2012 and `outdate`s from 1997 to 2012. I do not understand how the lines below could result in a `monthstoadd = 62844` (which blow some time offsets up). Can it be the conversion to uint16 for the use in a loop? Why, and what could one do instead?

The lines below apply to data where `INDATUMA` and `UTDATUMA` are of the format 20071231, e.g. Date parsing seems to work for `indate` and `outdate`, those values make sense.
(I am showing more code than strictly necessary, as my assumptions about what should work are clearly wrong somewhere, so maybe I'm wrong on what breaks. The data structure comes from pandas.)

```
all_treatments['indate'] = pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['INDATUMA'], errors='coerce',format='%Y%m%d')
all_treatments['outdate'] = pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['UTDATUMA'], errors='coerce',format='%Y%m%d')
all_treatments['extramonths'] = 12*(all_treatments['outdate'].dt.year-all_treatments['indate'].dt.year)+(all_treatments['outdate'].dt.month-all_treatments['indate'].dt.month)
emcolix     = all_treatments.columns.get_loc('extramonths')
for i in range(0,originalN):
    monthstoadd = all_treatments.iloc[i,emcolix].astype('uint16')
    for x in range(0,monthstoadd):
```

The final line shows a loop which breaks at `x = 3174` with `monthstoadd = 62844`, which makes no sense for the date range I use.

Answer (score 2):

The default dtype for integers in a Pandas Series is `int64` -- a *signed* 64-bit integer.

```
In [82]: pd.Series([-2692]).dtype
Out[82]: dtype('int64')
```

If you use `astype` to convert the dtype to `uint16` -- an *unsigned* 16-bit integer -- then `int64` values which are outside the range of ints representable as `uint16`s get cast to `uint16` values. For example, the negative `int64` -2692 gets mapped to 62844 as a `uint16`:

```
In [80]: np.array([-2692], dtype='int64').astype('uint16')
Out[80]: array([62844], dtype=uint16)
```

---

Here is the range of ints representable as `int64`s:

```
In [83]: np.iinfo('int64')
Out[83]: iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)
```

And here is the range of ints representable as `uint16`s:

```
In [84]: np.iinfo('uint16')
Out[84]: iinfo(min=0, max=65535, dtype=uint16)
```

---

To debug problems like this it is useful to isolate a toy example which exhibits the problem. For example, if you run

```
for i in range(0,originalN):
    monthstoadd = all_treatments.iloc[i,emcolix].astype('uint16')
    if monthstoadd == 62844:
        print(all_treatments.iloc[i,emcolix])
        print(all_treatments.iloc[i,emcolix].dtype)
        break
```

then you would see the value of `all_treatments.iloc[i,emcolix]` before calling `astype`, and also the `dtype`. This would be a good starting point to discover the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I expected this. I don't have negative values, and the max is a few thousand, in the range for uint16. Or a uint16 still trips up loop parsing?

Comment: What is the dtype of `all_treatments['extramonths']`?  There should be no problem using a `uint16` in a loop.

Comment: Thanks, I am double checking my values for negatives. That said, -2692 would be a major coding error in the data (someone leaving the hospital 224 years before she entered — this is still inconsistent with the date ranges I checked).